# How can I make a discord bot take a message and turn it into a varable?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

Please be forgivable with my code, this is my first ever project with py. I'd like it to turn a message user like "/channel http://youtube.com@youtube" to a variable like "channelID" that can be used later in the py.
I'm working with this so far.

```
import discord
import re
import easygui
from easygui import *
from re import search
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json
import base64
import os
import webbrowser
import pyperclip
import win32com.client as comclt
import time
import pyautogui
import discord
 
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
 
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
client.run('token')
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
 
    if message.content.startswith('/channel '):
        channelURL = message.content()
 


        if search("http", channelURL):
            if re.search("://", channelURL):
                if re.search("youtu", channelURL):
                    
                    # Loads page data #
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(channelURL, cookies={'CONSENT': 'YES+1'}).text, "html.parser")
                    data = re.search(r"var ytInitialData = ({.*});", str(soup.prettify())).group(1)
                    json_data = json.loads(data)
                    
                    # Finds channel information #
                    channel_id   = json_data["header"]["c4TabbedHeaderRenderer"]["channelId"]
                    channel_name = json_data["header"]["c4TabbedHeaderRenderer"]["title"]
                    channel_logo = json_data["header"]["c4TabbedHeaderRenderer"]["avatar"]["thumbnails"][2]["url"]
                    channel_id_link = "https://youtube.com/channel/"+channel_id
                    
                    
                    # Prints Channel information to console #
                    print("Channel ID: "+channel_id)
                    print("Channel Name: "+channel_name)
                    print("Channel Logo: "+channel_logo)
                    print("Channel ID: "+channel_id_link)
                    
                    # Creates HTML file var# 
                    f = open('channelid.html','w')
                    
                
                    # Converts and downlaods image file to png # 
                    imgUrl = channel_logo
                    filename = "image.png".split('/')[-1]
                    r = requests.get(imgUrl, allow_redirects=True)
                    open(filename, 'wb').write(r.content)
                    
        await message.channel.send(channel_id_link)
```

I tried to use

```
if message.content.startswith('/channel '):
```

and

```
channelURL = message.content()
```

But I know I'm missing something really simple. I just can't put my finger on it.

I was `channelURL = message.content()` to store the variable of `if message.content.startswith('/channel '):`

Comment: Also client.run('token') should be at the end of the file

Comment: I'll fix this now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[discord.Message.content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.content) is a str and can't be called like a function i.e., `message.content()`.

Use `channelURL = message.content` instead.
Remember to enable message content intents.

Comment: I tried this 
``if message.content.startswith('channel'):
        print (message.content)
        channelURL = message.content``

but it didn't log any response.

Comment: Did you move client.run('token') to the end as suggested by @Ged0jzn4 ?

Comment: Yeah, just did.